# Envato API send POST request from server

Tags: php, wordpress, api, http-post

They are saying like:

> After the user has logged in and given their permission, the Envato
>   API will redirect them back to your application on the Confirmation
>   URL provided, with a single-use authentication code provided in the
>   query string (eg. http://your.app/callback?code=abc123...). You must
>   use this code to request an access token from the API, by sending the
>   following POST request from your server (encoded as
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded), replacing [CODE] with the code
>   you've just received, [CLIENT_SECRET] with your secret application
>   key, and the other fields as necessary:

```
POST https://api.envato.com/token
     grant_type=authorization_code&
     code=[CODE]&
     client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&
     client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]
```

I am able to get the code by $_GET('code');  how make a post request to above url?

Comment: Envato API has been changed recently, you can visit https://build.envato.com/api/ for updated one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to use curl or a similar library. Here's a quick tutorial about curl that includes a post: http://codular.com/curl-with-php. It even mentions oauth, which sounds like what you're doing.

Comment: Hello thanks, will it be possible to provide a code for it..i have not used the curl before and confused with the case above pls

Comment: Actually I'll edit my answer. A much better example can be found here: http://codular.com/curl-with-php